# How to manage .unstack() ValueError by adding a number a after a duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I know it seem similar to other question, but I can't find the solution on the link someone marked this question as duplicate. Maybe someone can explain. So here we are. I have a dataset (`df`) of time series as follow:

```
date          symbol    close
09/01/2018    ACA       132,1
10/01/2018    ACA       134,4
...
28/04/2013    BA        22,12
...
21/01/2016    DIL       180,01
...
```

The idea was to convert it as this:

```
date          ACA        BA        DIL
28/04/2013    NaN        22,12     NaN
...
21/01/2016    NaN        23        180,01
...
...
...
10/01/2018    134,4      32,2      181,3
```

As suggested by [Troy D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957768/8981559) It can be used `df.unstack()` as follow:

```
df = df.set_index(['date', 'symbol'])
df = df.unstack()
df = df['close']
```

The problem is that I sometimes have multiple time series with the same "symbol". Therefore, if I do nothing this error appears:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Since I don't want them to be merged, how could I rename them following, for example, by 2,3, and so on to make easier to `unstack()`?

Comment: Is possible create sample data with duplicates and expected output? e.g. change `10/01/2018    ACA       134,4` to `09/01/2018    ACA       100` ?

Comment: because maybe it is not dupe?